# Is it possible to run every testing.xml file with different jenkins job?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I've around 100 test method in my `testing.xml` file. and that testing.xml configured in pom.xml file so I'm able to run my all those testcase as `maven test` and I'm getting the proper reports and all.

I have created one Jenkins job and configured `maven project` in that and mentioned pom.xml file path of local. I'm able to run successfully.

[image]

I'm planning to separate some testcase category wise and manage then in another `testing.xml` file. lest say 2 xml file having 50 50 test methods.

I'm stuck here. Is it possible to configure every testing.xml file in separate Jenkins job ? if yes then how do i configure ? (**Note:** I have to run maven test for getting the reports)

Comment: Why do you use a `testing.xml`. Just use the naming conventions of Maven and let maven-surefire/maven-failsafe do it's work...Is much more simpler...Why do you need to have different tests in different jobs via different testing.xml files? Separating unit and integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the xml file name as parameter to the maven test command. First need to change the pom file as follows.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${SuiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, you pass the different file name for each execution like,

```
mvn test -DSuiteXmlFile=mytestng1.xml
```

For second xml file,

```
mvn test -DSuiteXmlFile=mytestng1.xml
```

You can configure each jenkins job with different parameter.

Comment: Thanks murti, where I have to mention parameters in Jenkins?

Comment: In Goals and options, just enter  the following:     test -DSuiteXmlFile=mytestng1.xml

Comment: @thanks again, I will try and let you know the outcome